# ;=10 Is there such a use in Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded, stm32

I saw such an if loop in a project : ;=10

```
if (minute&lt;10)
  {
  //  Serial.print("0");
  //  Serial.print(minute, DEC);
  } 
  else if (minute&gt;=10)
  {
 //   Serial.print(minute, DEC);
  }
 // Serial.print(":");
  if (second&lt;10)
  {
  //  Serial.print("0");
   // Serial.print(second, DEC);
  } 
  else if (second&gt;=10)
  {
  //  Serial.print(second, DEC);
  }
  //Serial.print(" ");
    //  Serial.print(day, DEC);
    //  Serial.print("/");
   //   Serial.print(month, DEC);
    //  Serial.print("/");
   //   Serial.println(year, DEC);
   //   Serial.print("RAKIM-HIZ ");
   //   Serial.print(gps.f_altitude());
   //   Serial.print("m ");
   //   Serial.print(gps.f_speed_kmph());
   //   Serial.println("km/h");
}
```

this is a GPS code

also in the same code

```
#include &lt;TinyGPS.h&gt;
#include &lt;String.h&gt;
```

they had.
i haven't seen this in C or similar language before, what does it mean?

Comment: `&lt;` is HTML encoding for `<`, and `&gt;` is `>`.  Those encodings don't belong in actual C++ code.

Comment: Perhaps you have seen this in HTML; these are named entities. Someone wanted to embed the code in HTML and had to escape the angle brackets `<>` as `&lt;` (less than) and `&gt;` (greater than).

Comment: `&gt;` looks like some code that broke going through an HTML parser. [That's the HTML character entity for `>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

Comment: You probably have some raw HTML or markdown text here. `&gt;` stands for the `>` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's code that was HTML encoded.  `&lt;` is the encoding for the `<` character and `&gt;` is the encoding for the `>` character.

So this:

```
#include &lt;TinyGPS.h&gt;
#include &lt;String.h&gt;

...

if (minute&lt;10)
{
    ...
} 
else if (minute&gt;=10)
{
    ...
}

if (second&lt;10)
{
    ...
} 
else if (second&gt;=10)
{
    ...
}
```

Is actually this:

```
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <String.h>

...

if (minute<10)
{
    ...
} 
else if (minute>=10)
{
    ...
}

if (second<10)
{
    ...
} 
else if (second>=10)
{
    ...
}
```

Also note that this code won't compile as-is.